# Is there a way to find the volume of an intersection between two box colliders in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project using unity 3d and need to calculate the volume of the intersection between the box colliders of objects in a scene. The box collider class doesn't seem to have any function to do that.
Any help please?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in for this.

Comment: Please do you know of any way to do it?

Comment: With math, probably. But no, I'm not mathy enough to work that out myself. Is it possible? Yes. Do I know how?  No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Physics.ComputePenetration()`
It can be used to determine a bit more than whether they just intersect, but if that's all you need it does the job fine.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html

Feed it the right arguments, and it'll return true if the colliders overlap.

Example:

```
BoxCollider box1; //first collider
BoxCollider box2; //second collider
float distance; //how far they need to move apart
Vector3 direction; //which direction they need to move apart in
bool hasCollided = ComputePenetration(  box1, box1.transform.position, box1.transform.rotation, 
                                        box2, box2.transform.position, box2.transform.rotation, 
                                        out direction, out distance);
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way though ...